# I´m trying to set up a command which scans the scoreboard if a specific player has any deaths, and if so, a region of blocks should be replaced w/ air

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This doesn´t work and I dont know why, please any suggestions. Thank you!

```
/execute if entity @e[type=player,scores={Deaths=1}] run fill -427 4 81 -430 20 200 minecraft:air
```

Comment: If you are gonna use `@e[type=player]` you can just use `@a` instead. What is the name and criteria of your scoreboard? Remember names are case sensitive. You can also use `scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Deaths` to watch the scoreboard scores

Comment: yes, I already used the scoreboard display. The criterias for the scoreboards are: /scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount and /scoreboard objectives setdisplay list Deaths

Comment: What numbers are on deathcount? if it is above or below 1, the command will not trigger. Try suing `say test` instead of `fill`

Comment: The count is on 1 and tbh I dont know what you mean by say test?

Comment: the command `/say A Message Here`. Just change the command after `run` to `say test`. If your player is at the right deathcount and is being targeted appropriatly by the execute, you will get a message on chat. If you do get a message, your problem is the `fill` command, if you don't get a message, your problem is in the target of `if entity <target>`

Comment: So I wrote /execute if entity @a[scores={Deaths=1}] run say Hii now and it doesnt give me the message Hii

Comment: Try typing in `/scoreboard objectives modify ` and at the very end the game will autofill with all score names. Display names may be different from the actual scoreboard name. If the name that appears is indeed Deaths, then i have absolutly no clue on the problem. I just tested it here, copying paste your commands and it worked normally.

Comment: So now it says: Showing 1 objective on scoreboards: Deaths; display as "Deaths" and is type "deathCount"

Comment: Then I have no clue. I did the exact same thing and had success. Are you typing it in chat or inside a command block? Try in chat. You can try and record a video and upload it here, maybe that will help.

Comment: I typed the scoreboard commands in chat and the "/execute if entity @a[scores={Deaths=1}] run say Hii" in a command block which I activate with a button

Comment: Try the execute in the chat, i mean.

Comment: Yes, I already did, but by the way which version did u try it in? If I type it in chat it says: the entitity UUID provided is in an invalid format.

Comment: Java 1.17.1 . The @a[...] should work for versions prior to 1.17, maybe up until 1.12. But you are using the new version of execute, so you surely are above 1.12

Comment: Yeah hm, then I dont know why it doesn`t work but hanks for the try!

Comment: Oh I solved it, I switched from version 1.12 to 1.16.4! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`/execute as @a if score @s deaths matches 1.. run fill -427 4 81 -430 20 200 air`

**What this does:** executes the function as every player, then checks if the player it's executing on has deaths of >= 1, then fills the region if all checks match

**Edit:** `/execute as @a[scores={Deaths=1..}] run fill -427 4 81 -430 20 200 air` also works

Comment: Op isn't asking what the command does, he is asking why it isn't working. Answer is on the comment section. Also, if you are gonna do `scores={Deaths=1}`, it should be `1..`

Comment: @BunnyMerz I know that's not what OP is asking for, but if you're going to use code you found somewhere, its important you know what it does